# Can't debug c++ code in android studio after updating to 3.1.2

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk, lldb

After updating `android studio` to `version 3.1.2` , I can't debug the app. When try to debug it shows on `emulator/Device` as on the picture given below [image]

and on error log

```
    Execution finished
com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: Execution finished
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.ExecutionResult.get(ExecutionResult.java:38)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.backend.lldb.LLDBDriver.getProtobufClient(LLDBDriver.java:90)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.backend.lldb.LLDBDriver.executeConsoleCommand(LLDBDriver.java:1109)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.backend.lldb.LLDBDriver.executeConsoleCommand(LLDBDriver.java:1103)
    at com.android.tools.ndk.run.lldb.AndroidLLDBDriver.loadStartupScripts(AndroidLLDBDriver.java:321)
    at com.android.tools.ndk.run.lldb.AndroidLLDBDriver.commonLoad(AndroidLLDBDriver.java:132)
    at com.android.tools.ndk.run.lldb.AndroidLLDBDriver.loadForAttach(AndroidLLDBDriver.java:248)
    at com.android.tools.ndk.run.AndroidNativeAppDebugProcess.prepareTarget(AndroidNativeAppDebugProcess.java:101)
    at com.android.tools.ndk.run.AndroidNativeDebugProcessImpl.doLoadTarget(AndroidNativeDebugProcessImpl.java:123)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.CidrDebugProcess.lambda$start$0(CidrDebugProcess.java:314)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.CidrDebugProcess$MyCommandProcessor.consume(CidrDebugProcess.java:703)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.CidrDebugProcess$MyCommandProcessor.consume(CidrDebugProcess.java:693)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.lambda$null$0(QueueProcessor.java:93)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:246)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.lambda$wrappingProcessor$1(QueueProcessor.java:93)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.lambda$null$3(QueueProcessor.java:226)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:246)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.lambda$startProcessing$4(QueueProcessor.java:226)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.intellij.execution.ExecutionFinishedException: Execution finished
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.backend.lldb.LLDBDriver$4.processTerminated(LLDBDriver.java:248)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor89.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$5.invoke(ProcessHandler.java:239)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.processTerminated(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$4.run(ProcessHandler.java:196)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$TasksRunner.execute(ProcessHandler.java:272)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyTerminated(ProcessHandler.java:177)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyProcessTerminated(ProcessHandler.java:173)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.BaseOSProcessHandler.onOSProcessTerminated(BaseOSProcessHandler.java:192)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.OSProcessHandler.onOSProcessTerminated(OSProcessHandler.java:89)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.BaseOSProcessHandler$2$1.consume(BaseOSProcessHandler.java:155)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.BaseOSProcessHandler$2$1.consume(BaseOSProcessHandler.java:140)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessWaitFor$1.run(ProcessWaitFor.java:66)
    ... 5 more
```

and the message was

Execution finished

Process finished with `exit code 0`
..................................................................................................................................

Comment: install `LLDB` from sdk tools

Comment: I install LLDB. But no change in error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after I uninstall the current version and re-install it again.